# How to make a custom DataLoader return values and labels seperately?

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, dataloader

I want to iterate over a custom DataLoader using batches with matching values and labels. Modification of PandasDataset described below is needed and since I copied it from online I do not have a great grasp of how it works

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class PandasDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.dataframe.iloc[index]


d = {'values': [1, 2], 'values2': [3, 4],'labels': [5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dataset = PandasDataset(df)
loader = DataLoader(torch.tensor(dataset), batch_size=1, shuffle=False)

for batch_index, (values, label) in enumerate(loader):
    print(values)
    print(label)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `__getitem__` to something like this:

```py
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        data = self.dataframe.iloc[index].to_numpy()
        return data[:-1], data[-1]
```

Then, you don't need to wrap your dataset with `torch.tensor`:

```py
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
```

and it'll return:

```py
next(iter(loader))
# >>> [tensor([[1, 3]]), tensor([5])]
```

Comment: Is there any way I could transform it to tensor? I am reshaping it before sending it to DataLoader. To call .reshape() it must be a tensor

Comment: @MariusKuzm yes, but which shape do you need? numpy arrays can be reshaped too

Comment: I am reshaping 2343x256 into 2343x16x16 and adding the label to make it 2343x16x16x1. Good idea im gonna attempt to reshape using numpy

Comment: I managed to reshape the tensor to 2343x16x16x1 but cannot insert the labels to the x1 dimension. Currently using:

Xy = torch.cat((X, torch.tensor(y.values)), dim=3)

Comment: @MariusKuzm I think it'll be easier if you open a new question with all the info. Make sure to post the shape of the relevant variables and the complete traceback of any error you might be facing.